# How to connect multiple teams bots to one Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure, botframework

I have an Azure bot service which is connected to the Azure App Service. I have the teams channel as one of the configured channels in the Azure bot Service. Currently my Azure bot service works fine for one bot. However I am not sure how to add teams bot in the same azure bot service. From the references I see here: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/2258#issuecomment-280506334 , looks like there are multiple appIds which indicate that multiple Azure bots need to be created. Instead can I have multiple teams bot connect to one single Azure bot ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a procedure of connecting multiple bots to one platform. But there is no such procedure available to get multiple teams apps in the channel section of azure bot services to connect with on azure bot service. Here is the bot created with multi-tenant feature with different ID’s can use this app. ID’s will be client ID’s. But we cannot connect multiple team's channels to one single bot service.

[image]

[image]

In configurations we can perform authentication required to connect multiple clients to the bot.

[image]

[image]

It can be a feature request to connect multiple team's bot to one single azure bot service.